# Maximum number of Resources for this API has been reached. Please contact AWS if you need additional Resources in AWS Rest API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've swagger JSON which I want to import on REST API Gateway, but I'm getting the message of
 `Maximum number of Resources for this API has been reached. Please contact AWS if you need additional Resources.` when I import. What should I do, it says I need additional resources. Where I can add additional resources on API Gateway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-execution-service-limits-table), the default limit for `Resources per API` is **300**. The error msg you have suggest that you are exceeding the limit.

Since the `Resources per API` limit can be increased (some limits can't), you have to request such an increase from AWS. The [Increase account service quotas](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/request-service-quota-increase/) tutorial at AWS explains how to do it.

Comment: I've 470 endpoints, so how many quotas do i need?

Comment: Thank you, sir. You made my day, I've been trying to solve it for three days. 
I'm sorry, one more question. I asked for 600 quotas, and how long does it take to accept my increasing quota request? it's been 10 hours since I sent the request.

Comment: @yondkoo I depends on your support level, but I would expect 1-2 days.